# Problema para centrar un div

Tags: html, css

No entiendo porque no se centra el .container. Deberia ponerse en el medio de la pagina con solo utilizar justify content y align content pero no lo hace. Ya pregunte en varios lados y no logre que se centre. Le quite el width y height pero no funciona, nose cual es el error. Si pudieran ayudarme les agradeceria soy bastante nuevo en estas cosas.Adjunto mi CSS y HTML e imagén de mi sitio web.

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 8px;
}


.music-card{
width: 300px;
display: flex;
padding: 9px;
align-self: center;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
}

.btn-music{
display: flex;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
padding: 6px;
}

.music-card h3{
text-align: center;
}

.pausar-boton{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
align-self: center;
justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="music-card rock">
            <h3>Rock</h3>
        <div class="btn-music">
            <button id="botonRock">Escuchar</button>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="music-card latina">
            <h3>Latina</h3>
        <div class="btn-music"> 
            <button id="botonLatina">Escuchar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="music-card electronica">
            <h3>Electronica</h3>
        <div class="btn-music">
            <button id="botonElectronica">Escuchar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="music-card hip">
            <h3>Hip Hop</h3>
        <div class="btn-music"> 
            <button id="botonHip">Escuchar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pausar-boton">
    <button class="pausar">Pausar</button>
</div>
```

IMAGÉN

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que quieres centrar? porque .container es la caja padre y está centrado...

Comment: Si esta centrado, no lo aprecias porque al contenedor padre no le haz asignado una altura, por lo que esta acoplado solo a los elementos en su interior.